# MySQL Support VSS (Volume Shadow Copy)?

Tags: mysql, volume-shadow-service

I know that MS SQL supports VSS. But does MySQL support VSS too??

Thanks

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment. It has a feature request for it to be added but no news on that yet.